# Avoid auto persist when deleting document from embedded association

Tags: mongoid

MongoID currently auto persist the parent document along with the embedded association when removing anything from the embed-many association. Is there a way to avoid this auto persist?

**Document model**

User has many embedded hobbies

Both the method below auto persist meaning it makes call to DB.

```
user.hobbies.pop 
user.hobbies = [hobby1]
```

I need to avoid that because I am doing a bulk operation on list of users and want to save extra db calls that are made for embedded associations.